# Problem calling function with web3.eth.contract

Tags: web3js

How come when I call a function and pass it parameters, it spits out an error? I try to print the updated name (`UPDATED`) but it's unable to pass it back.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var myContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"string"}],"name":"setTokenName","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenName","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}])
var contractInstance = myContract.at('0x8b3c0bf558d5b25a91d8c5a5cbc48648285ad136');

contractInstance.setTokenName('UPDATED');

var updatedresult = contractInstance.get();

console.log(`updated name should be here: ${updatedresult}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read from the contract, it doesn't require gas(?), but when you write to the contract it requires gas so you need to set a defaultAccount.

Resolved using:
`web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You should probabaly instantiate myContract using the new operator and capitalise contract so it becomes this:

> ```
> var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"string"}],"name":"setTokenName","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenName","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}])
> ```

But where did you get the **at** function from ? It is not a function in the web3 library

> var contractInstance = myContract.at('0x8b3c0bf558d5b25a91d8c5a5cbc48648285ad136');

**EDIT**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([{
"constant":true,
"inputs":[],
"name":"get",
"outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],
"payable":false,
"stateMutability":"view",
"type":"function"},
{"constant":false,
"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"string"}],
"name":"setTokenName",
"outputs":[],
"payable":false,
"stateMutability":"nonpayable",
"type":"function"},
{"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenName","type":"string"}],
"payable":false,
"stateMutability":"nonpayable",
"type":"constructor"}],'0x61edcdf5bb736adffe5043706e7c5bb1f1a56eea');



myContract.methods.setTokenName('UPDATED');
var updatedresult = myContract.methods.get().call({"from": 
'0x8b3c0bf558d5b25a91d8c5a5cbc48648285ad136'}).then(console.log);
console.log(`updated name should be here: ${updatedresult}`);
```

Comment: I'm following the Web3 JavaScript app API and it tells me to use the at function. It works properly when I do other function calls (like a get method), but calling an update method (setTokenName) causes an error

Comment: Could you link me to the page ? Maybe I can understand better then. I am looking at the official web3.js library page and cant find anything: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract

Comment: Yeah sure, https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: Hey what version of web3 are you using? i think dependent on that, it differs on how you declare variables. I am using 1.0.0-beta.23 . I have changed the code to reflect that. Its in the edit of my answer.

Comment: Where are you getting the "methods" statement from?

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract       

Its the new web3 library, thats what you use to call your functions